# How to stop multiple bootstrap modals opening on form submission

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a page with multiple forms, they open in modal windows for the user to fill out.

The problem is, when the user submits the form (success or error), all the other modal windows open, not just the one that was being filled out.

On submission the page reloads, so I have jQuery scripts to open the modal to show the error or success message.

I have tried to give each modal a specific ID but when the form is submitted .modal('show'); seems to cause all modals to open.

How can I fix this? Any advice on fixing the issue and cleaning up my Jquery code would be much appreciated.

Here is my markup:

```
    <!-- Course Details -->
    <div>

    <!-- Heading -->
    <h2>An introduction to physiotherapy for the geriatric patient</h2>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient">
      Register Interest
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patientLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header br-lblue">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient">"An introduction to physiotherapy for the geriatric patient" Booking Form</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="form_an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient">
            <form id="form3_cpd_course_signup" action="/continued-professional-development/" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form3_name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" type="text" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form3_email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your email" type="email" required="required" />
                </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <input id="form3_submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" value="Send" type="submit" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Modal -->
</div>

<!-- Course Details -->
<div>

    <!-- Heading -->
    <h2>Tissue Repair with Professor Tim Watson</h2>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient">
      Register Interest
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watsonLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header br-lblue">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson">"Tissue Repair with Professor Tim Watson" Booking Form</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="form_tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson">
            <form id="form3_cpd_course_signup" action="/continued-professional-development/" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form3_name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" type="text" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form3_email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your email" type="email" required="required" />
                </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <input id="form3_submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" value="Send" type="submit" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Modal -->
</div>
```

And here is the script at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form#form_an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient .required').attr('required', 'required');  

        var error = $('#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient .error').html(); 
        var success = $('#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient .success').html();  

        if (error != null) { 
            $('#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patientLabel').empty().text('Error Sending Registration'); 
        }

        if (success != null) {
            $('#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patientLabel').empty().text('Registration Delivered');
        } 

        if ((error != null) || (success != null)) { $('#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient').modal('show'); } 
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form#form_tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson .required').attr('required', 'required');  

        var error = $('#tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson .error').html(); 
        var success = $('#tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson .success').html();  

        if (error != null) { 
            $('#tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watsonLabel').empty().text('Error Sending Registration'); 
        }

        if (success != null) {
            $('#tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watsonLabel').empty().text('Registration Delivered');
        } 

        if ((error != null) || (success != null)) { $('#tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson').modal('show'); } 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using a submit on the button type for the form submission?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to place your javascript under one document.ready to start, then I named the error and success variables differently based on what dom element they were pulling from. This should help you.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var error = $('#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient .error').html(); 
    var success = $('#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient .success').html();  
    var tissueError = $('#tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson .error').html(); 
    var tissueSuccess = $('#tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson .success').html();  

    if (error != null) { 
        $('#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patientLabel').empty().text('Error Sending Registration'); 
    }

    if (success != null) {
        $('#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patientLabel').empty().text('Registration Delivered');
    } 

    if ((error != null) || (success != null)) { $('#an-introduction-to-physiotherapy-for-the-geriatric-patient').modal('show'); } 

    $('form#form_tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson .required').attr('required', 'required');  


    if (tissueError != null) { 
        $('#tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watsonLabel').empty().text('Error Sending Registration'); 
    }

    if (tissueSuccess != null) {
        $('#tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watsonLabel').empty().text('Registration Delivered');
    } 

    if ((tissueError != null) || (tissueSuccess != null)) { $('#tissue-repair-with-professor-tim-watson').modal('show'); } 
  });
```

Comment: Hey Mack, thanks so much for looking at this for me. I'm still finding that on submission (success or error) it is still opening all modals on top each other.